kotlin-reflect error while getting the release of the app in android kotlin
When I try to create a signed apk, I get a kotlin reflect error.
`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.30.
Required by:
project :app > com.yodo1.mas:full:4.11.0 > com.yodo1.mas.mediation:inmobi:4.11.0 > com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads-kotlin:10.6.2
> Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DefaultDependencyResolveDetails.`

Ad SDK does not support Kotlin Reflect version. I'm trying to update my version but the same error persists.
